# (postcss : not found) error I found when installing tailwindcss for my project

Tags: javascript, css, tailwind-css

i want to use tailwind css with postcss but I have an issue with installation can anybody solve it?
my package . js is

```
{
"name": "ninja-food",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
    "build": "postcss ./src/styles.css -o ./public/styles.css"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.8",
    "postcss": "^8.4.16",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8"
}
```

}

afer tailwind init i didnot get postcss.config.js file so i have manualy create it and put code in it.

```
    module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  }
}
```

but i am again getting error that is saying postcss not found

Comment: You have to install postcss-cli, postcss package can't be used direcly via cli but only in js

Answer (score 0):

install postcss using npm `npm install postcss` and run your project again.